# apache 2.4.6 vhosts + mod_proxy get AH00872: APR_BUCKET_IS_EOS

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, tomcat7

I'm using VH and proxy to serve multiple backend tomcat instances.  Currently chasing around this problem with a JSP file.

The proxy is getting the correct URL to tomcat via ajp://localhost:8009/MYAPPTAG/.  I see in the logs that the connection was made.  However the JSP being called doesn't appear to do anything but fail silently.

AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
 AH01143: Running scheme ajp handler (attempt 0)
 AH00895: serving URL ajp://localhost/tomcat-context/code.jsp

AH00944: connecting ajp://localhost/tomcat-context/code.jsp to localhost:8009
 AH00947: connected /tomcat-context/code.jsp to localhost:8009 
 AH00872: APR_BUCKET_IS_EOS
 AH00873: data to read (max 8186 at 4)
 AH00875: got 0 bytes of data
 AH00892: got response from [::1]:8009 (localhost)

I'm stumped.  Any pointers on where/how to debug this?

Oh and since I know absolutely zero HTML, this post is going to be mangled.

-weq

Comment: Found mod_log_forensic.  Bumped up the logging to trace5 for mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp.  With that, I found a Cookie was being passed around through the proxy.  Had to add a ReverseCookiePath directive to manage it.  Works fine now.